# Ruby delete space not working correctly

Tags: ruby

Below is the code:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :019 > "a, , b, c".delete(" , ") 
 => "abc"
```

I want it to be

```
a, b, c
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete` removes all characters occuring in the string you hand over to it (see [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-delete)). What you need is something like

```
"a, , b, c".gsub(/(\s*,\s*)+/, ', ')
```

**UPDATE**:

As mentioned in a comment below, the string is the result of a `join(', ')`. In this case the better approach would be to remove the empty/`nil` elements before joining, i.e.

```
array.compact.join(', ')                      # if some elements are nil
array.delete_if(:&empty?).join(', ')          # if some elements are ''
array.compact.delete_if(:&empty?).join(', ')  # if both can occur
```

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser: Do you have a bot for that comment? ;-) For what my proposal is doing you need a regexp (or much more code). The specification of the problem is not very clear though.

Comment: @Victor: E.g. `"a, ,b, c".gsub(/\s*, (,\s*)*/, ', ')` is `"a, b, c"` while `"a, ,b, c".gsub(' , ', '')` is `""a, ,b, c""`.

Comment: I actually use `.join(', ')` before I wanna `gsub` it. So I think no regex is needed. Thanks.

Comment: undur: No, I don't have a bot. :) I get a little surprised when people use regexes even for substituting fixed strings. I see that that's not what you're doing here, but I think this goes beyond the scope of the original problem. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Victor: Then, a regexp is not needed. But please see the update of my answer.

Comment: I am actually using `compact`, can I make it more robust with this: `array.compact.delete_if(:&empty?).join(', ')`?

Comment: @Victor: If you can have `nil` and `''` in your array, then yes.

Comment: So I don't even need `gsub` then?

Comment: @Victor: You don't need. Another problem can be Strings like `" "`. But those will be a problem with your accepted solution anyway.

Comment: Ok, your persistence won me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs (paraphrased): `String#delete` deletes all characters individually, so in your case it will remove all spaces and all commas. What you want is probably `"a, , b, c".gsub(' , ', '')`.

Comment: Yes, closer to the original attempt and without regexp (+1). However, with a regexp you can fix possible comma errors in a more general way. E.g. your solution will transfer `"a , b"` to `"ab"`.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `"a, , b, c".gsub(' ,', '')`

http://codepad.org/weqgKd91

Answer (score 0):

According to [ruby api](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-delete) **delete** removes all characters which are in the parameter.
In your case it is both space and comma.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```
"a, , b, c".gsub(/\s+,/, "")
```

which does the following:

```
irb(main):035:0> "a, , b, c".gsub(/\s+,/, "")
=> "a, b, c"
```

Comment: That won't do quite what the OP wanted.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser: Oh yes, it does. It outputs `"a, b, c"` as requested. Everything else is just guessing.